# Sendbox testing

Tags: android, payment, android-pay

I am in India, Integrating Android pay very first time, Don't know how to test with android pay.

Please help me to integrate send box account, Every time I am adding test card getting error "This card can't be added to android pay"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Pay is not supported on Indian cards, Google has instead launched Tez for Indian market.

Update: Ask your client to give you a card from one of the supporting banks, see list here support.google.com/androidpay/topic/7351519

Comment: I am a developer now what I need to do at my end if I want's to integrate for my client

Comment: Ask your client to give you a card from one of the supporting banks, see list here https://support.google.com/androidpay/topic/7351519

Comment: Yes it's working with my client card. Post your answer so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
Card card = new Card()
        .setNumber("5555555555554444")
        .setExpMonth("01")
        .setExpYear("99")
        .setCvc("123")
        .setAddressZip("12345");
```